# How would you install Gitweb in shared hosting?

Tags: git, gitweb

I recently installed my git in my shared hosting now I want to install gitweb but I don't know how to install and configure it.

Do you have any process to share on gitweb installation?

Answer (score 4):

The [gitweb section of the git repo](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tree;f=gitweb;h=b811d5a45d1a3d6f2d1101b383c99675e9323b7f;hb=HEAD) does contain detailed [installation instructions](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/INSTALL;hb=HEAD).

To quote just the first section:

## GIT web Interface (gitweb) Installation

> First you have to generate `gitweb.cgi` from `gitweb.perl` using "`make gitweb`", then "`make install-gitweb`" appropriate files (`gitweb.cgi`, `gitweb.js`, `gitweb.css`, `git-logo.png` and `git-favicon.png`) to their destination.
>   For example if `git` was (or is) installed with `/usr` prefix and `gitwebdir` is `/var/www/cgi-bin`, you can do:

```
$ make prefix=/usr gitweb                            ;# as yourself
# make gitwebdir=/var/www/cgi-bin install-gitweb     ;# as root
```

> Alternatively you can use `autoconf` generated `./configure` script to set up path to git binaries (via `config.mak.autogen`), so you can write instead

```
$ make configure                     ;# as yourself
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr          ;# as yourself
$ make gitweb                        ;# as yourself
# make gitwebdir=/var/www/cgi-bin \
       install-gitweb                ;# as root
```

> The above example assumes that your web server is configured to run `[executable]` files in `/var/www/cgi-bin/` as server scripts (as CGI scripts).